# Convert R code into Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, tensor

I need to write in Matlab this portion of the package "tensor" which is written in R. Unfortunately I am not used to R code style.

where `A=matrix(sample(0:1, 2 * 3, replace = TRUE), 2, 3)`
here the code in R:

```
  A <- as.array(A)
  dimA <- dim(A)
  dnA <- dimnames(A)      

  seqA <- seq(along=dimA)
  allA <- length(seqA) == length(alongA)
  permA <- c(seqA[-alongA], alongA)
  if (!all(seqA == permA))
    A <- aperm(A, permA)
  dim(A) <- c(
    if (allA) 1 else prod(dimA[-alongA]),
    prod(dimA[alongA])
  )
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

alongA is undefined; the R code is incomplete. could you provide a working sample?